# Image Swiping In Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm just a beginner to iphone development.

Recently i'm doing a project in which images need to be swiped. Could any one help me with it?

The images are stored in a server whose link is given. 
I'm need it badly. So please help me

thank you

Comment: Welcome beginner! I was in your shoes not so long ago.

Comment: Hey, do you want animation while swipe, or just want one image come after another(randomly)

Comment: no need of animation just need to swipe the images one after the other it doesn't matter if its random or not. But the images are present in the server not in the iphone

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

- You could either look at using a [Paging Scroll View](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/05/22/iphone-uiscrollview-with-paging-example/)
- Or, You could look at getting a series of UIImageViews with the correct images in each and then setting up a [UISwipeGestureRecogniser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) for both directions. On the swipe's event handler you can adjust the x and y positions of the imageViews.

This is basic stuff. You should read some of the How-to's on Apple's developer website to help you with the base knowledge.

Edit:

Regarding the Internet images, the code can be adapted into the paging scroll view example:

```
NSString *path = @"http://merrimusings.mu.nu/archives/images/groundhog2.jpg";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO];
```

Load the strings from an NSMutableArray instead and you're good to go!

Comment: actually the images has to be viewed as that in the photo album of iphone but the images are stored in the server.

Comment: Both links I provided have sample code. We will **help** you not do it for you.

Comment: 2nd link is page not found

Comment: @mfamous that's because this answer is > 3 years old

Answer (score 1):

Use Three20 photo Album. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: I think the OP is going to run into trouble using an external library, they don't have the base knowledge to be able to adapt code. I know because it wasn't so long ago that I was in his position. Using an external library as a beginner would have been a little too much for me.

Comment: @Daniel Hanly but somewhere in his career he need to learn using external library.

Comment: I agree with you, but they are extensions of the Apple provided code set, so it would be necessary to be able to use that first and then you can look at an external library and decide how you can build that functionality into your existing code.

Comment: @Daniel Hanly Yes You are right. Thanks for your suggestions. I'll keep them in mind.